# rclone using too much download bandwidth

Tags: backup

I'm using the latest version of rclone to copy lots of files to backblaze b2 storage. What I've noticed recently is that there is a lot more download bandwidth being used than upload bandwidth. Eg running iftop on the network interface being used these are typical figures:-

Upload 77.6KB/s
Download 1.32MB/s

1. Why is there such so much being downloaded if all I am doing is backing up files to the server?
2. What can I do lessen the download bandwidth?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `-bwlimit` option to reduce download bandwidth?